# How to get param value in Zend if it contains special characters?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I have a search action in Zend Framework.

And code is:

```
function searchAction()
{
    $keyword = $this->getRequest()->getParam('keyword');
    if( !empty($keyword) )
    {
        //@todo here
    }
}
```

I use the url like below to post keyword to the action:

> /index/search/keyword/**google**

With:

- index:   controller
- search:  action
- keyword & google: a pair of param and value.

Everything is OK until the user searches the keyword with value is "/" character

> /index/search/keyword/**/**
>   **=>**: getParam('keyword') is empty

I have tried to use %2F (which is encoded of "/")

> /index/search/keyword/**%2F**
>   **=>**: 404 Error

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post as `/index/search?keyword=%2F` instead? I've had to resort to that because I wasn't sure how to handle this situation as well. `$this->_request->getParams()` should still return it as a parameter in the array.

Comment: @Benno: You are right, but, I need to keep that pair key and value of `keyword` param. So if I use ?keyword=value => when I user `url` helper such as: $this->url(); => it will lost this param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add route in your bootstrap.php

```
$router = $frontController->getRouter();

$router->addRoute(
        'searchOncontrollername',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/controllername/search/:keyword', array('controller' => 'controllername',
                                                          'action' => 'search'
            )));
```

after that you can work with variable keyword in controller:

```
$keyword  = $this->getRequest()->getParam("keyword");
```

Comment: Really, event I got found 404 error, I believe that it is from Apache?

Answer (score 2):

try simple use:

```
$value = $this->_getParam('keyword');
```